# ngRoute causing Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I am using AngularJS ngRoute to switch the view. I am loading Javascript/Jquery library files on `$(document).ready(function(){...});`
But at that time all the DOM are not loading as I am using ngRoute.

If I go to that specific page and reload once the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null` vanishes.

Kindly help me what should I use rather than `$(document).ready(function(){...});`
So that my Application get rid of the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`

Thanks

Comment: I think if I load the specific script only if the DOM comes to focus, then this issue may be solved.

Comment: just a suggestion don't use jquery with angularjs :)

Comment: Yes @anoop thanks, I am using jquery for some user interface functionality.